# Https blocks jquery and css files

Tags: joomla-3.x, https

In http website is loading without any problem. When I changed to https it affects alignment.

Its not loading any CSS files and Js files in https.

Can any one suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: Please be more specific and perhaps provide a link to your website so we can test

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide a link to a page for an accurate answer, but my initial suspicion is that you'll be linking to a style sheet (or possibly javascript) with a full URL containing http rather than https.  If so, use relative links.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in the configuration file or in .htaccess? i changed the redirect rule in .htaccess but the browser ignores with the page is not redirecting properly and too many redirect messages

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there are external css or javascript files that are still linked through http. 
Most browsers will stop loading [**mixed content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent) and usually will throw warnings.

To answer your question-comment on Richard's answer, usually it's not something you have to do in the configuration or the htaccess file to fix this.

What you have to do, is to open your browser console and check for the errors and warnings. If you can't find something obvious in the console, then you should start examining the source code of your site. Start from the header and try to spot any external assets files that are linked with `"http://"` instead of `https://` or having relative links.

Keep going down to the body as well, as it's possible that http linked stuff might exist there as well.

After identifying those, you should find from where these files are getting called. It can be from the template, from modules, components etc.

Some extensions may give the option to change the way they load external files. Others might not. 
If you find any such extension, I would suggest to report this to its developer, in order to release an update with that will fix this issue.

More info on: [**"How to fix a website with mixed content"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)